# Can two people play the same game via Steam Family Sharing at the same time?

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

My brother owns *Skyrim* on Steam. We use Steam Family Sharing, but we were wondering how both of us could play it at the same time.

Answer (score 26):

Two people are actually able to play at the same time. I've done this myself before, and as far as I can tell, Steam has done nothing to block this.

If anyone can prove it's not legal / within their terms, then please comment below.

If you both share a game on Steam, then both of you download the game. If one of you goes into offline mode, you can play at the same time. This obviously blocks online features such as saving to the cloud and online gameplay, but considering Skyrim is single-player (without mods), it shouldn't be a problem. This will also not work with games that are DRM, which require you to be online to start playing.

Comment: This is how me and the girlfriend do it. It blocks online features but we were still able to play Borderlands 2 co-op by connecting my PC and her laptop with an ethernet cable.

Comment: As of recent, this hasn't been working for us.

Comment: @KOVIKO looks like the FAQ updated: "You must be online to access and play games which are shared with you."

Comment: @Corsaka That's always been the case. The difference, now, is that the person sharing the library with you is still tracked as playing the game even when *they* are offline. We haven't tested actually disabling the Internet connection, though.

Answer (score 24):

Two people can't play at the same moment on Steam Family Sharing.

[Family Sharing FAQ](http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing) clearly states this:

> **Can two users share a library and both play at the same time?**
>
> No, a shared library may only be accessed by one user at a time.

Comment: It's a shame you can't play two different games at the same time, though.

Comment: @MBraedley This is intentional. They want to make sure only one person at a time can be using games from a specific account.

Comment: This is only to, more or less, make it so you don't have to give your children your Steam account password.

Comment: It's mostly so it can't be abused and multiple people can just buy a game once and then play it at the same time. If you want to play at the same time go into offline mode, that's how me and the girlfriend do it.

Comment: @Powerlord It should work on a game-by-game basis though, as was the case with CDs. If I lend a book to a friend, I should still be able to read other books off my book stack.

Comment: @TheThunderChimp Should it? sure. But does it? Nope.

Comment: @TheThunderChimp I mean, you're barking up the wrong tree. We're not valve nor do we have contacts with them. If you want such a change, you should take it to valve, and not bring it up here.

Answer (score 10):

This is completely possible depending on the game (usually games that do not connect to the internet). After setting up family sharing, the person who owns the game must start the game. After the game is running, go to steam and go into offline mode. Now the second person can use family sharing. I've done this numerous times with Civ V and i believe should work with Skyrim.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Steam Family Sharing FAQ](http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing):

> Q: **Can two users share a library and both play at the same time?**
>
> A: *No, a shared library may only be accessed by one user at a time.*

Comment: You are way too fast

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Family sharing acts as though you were passing the account login back and forth.  Only one person can access any given account at one time.  So as soon your brother starts a game, you or anyone else is locked out.  It will not let you play as though you had two copies of the game.