# Friend shares his games with multiple people on family sharing but I get ejected

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

My friend shares his library with multiple people, including me. As he is the host of the library, if the playes a game then I get ejected. I understand that well. What I don't understand is this - if other guy from the list playes a shared game, I also get ejected. Which is weird, since if I was already playing a shared game, other people shouldn't be able to play them, and therefore not eject me. So what is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, whoever starts a game will kick off any other person already playing. The exception is for the account owner, who takes priority over everyone else.

There's a [Steam FAQ Page](https://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing) that seems vaguely helpful - I'll summarize the important parts here:

> **Can two users share a library and both play at the same time?**
> No, a shared library may only be accessed by one user at a time.

> **When I authorize a device to lend my library to others, do I limit my own ability to access and play my games?**
> As the account holder, you may always access and play your games at any time. If you decide to start playing when another user is already playing one of your games, he/she will be given a few minutes to either purchase the game or quit playing.

My understanding is that deciding to start playing will force anyone who isn't the account owner to quit.

There's also a [similar question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/251372/how-to-make-two-people-play-at-the-same-time) from Arqade in 2016 that uses an apt explanation:

> Family sharing acts as though you were passing the account login back and forth.

Comment: Alright, sure, but if that's the case then why I can't play the game after being ejected? After all, I should now be able to eject the currently playing player.

Comment: @Miloszun That is an interesting conundrum. I can't find any piece of information about that on the internet. It's possible there's an internal priority system - do you know which of you was added to Family Sharing first?

Comment: I think I am the last. Maybe it does work like this?

Comment: @Miloszun Totally uncertain, but it's the most likely explanation I can think of.

Comment: I used family sharing a long time ago and I think you get a warning, when starting a game, that you will kick any other player (except the owner) and you got the give confirmation whether that is ok. This was a few years back, so I might be wrong.